# WPF grid column resize

Tags: .net, wpf, grid, wpfdatagrid, resize

I am working with DataGrid and Grid , I want to resize column of grid (no matter Grid or DataGrid) by dragging  , not only in header row section (DataGrid) ,it must be in any cell .

I knew I should use GridSplitter , but I don't want define many columns as place for GridSplitter :for a normal grid with 20 columns , i will define 19 columns to make grid resizable , so confused !!!

so is there any way to make the grid column resizable , but don't change the structure of original grid in xaml